# How do I get the indexwise average of a array column with pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, pyspark

I have a df with a column `fftAbs` (absolute values acquired after an fft). The type of df['fftAbs'] is a `ArrayType(DoubleType())`. I want to get the indexwise average of all the values.
So if the column holds

```
// Random data
||fftAbs  ||
------------
|[0, 1, 2] |
|[2, 3, 12]|
|[1, 8, 4] |
```

I want to aquire a list like `[1, 4, 6]` (because 0+2+1/3 = 1, 1+3+8/3 = 4, 2+4+12/3 = 6)

I've tried using:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
avgDf = df.select(F.avg('fftAbs'))
```

but I'll get `AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'avg(fftAbs)' due to data type mismatch: function average requires numeric or interval types, not array<double>;`

EDIT:
I also tried

```
def _index_avg(twoDL):
    return np.mean(twoDL)

spark_index_avg = F.udf(_index_avg, T.ArrayType(T.DoubleType(), False))
avgDf = df.agg(spark_index_avg(F.collect_list('fftAbs')))
```

but then I got `net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype). This happens when an unsupported/unregistered class is being unpickled that requires construction arguments. Fix it by registering a custom IObjectConstructor for this class.`

Just for reference, my complete code is here (except from the first query):

```py
import numpy as np
import pyspark as ps
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def _rfft(x):
    transformed = np.fft.rfft(x)
    return map(lambda c: (c.real, c.imag),transformed.tolist())

spark_complexType = T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
        T.StructField("real", T.DoubleType(), False),
        T.StructField("imag", T.DoubleType(), False),
    ]), False)

spark_rfft = F.udf(_rfft, spark_complexType)

def _fft_bins(size, periodMicroSeconds):
    return np.fft.rfftfreq(size, d=(periodMicroSeconds/10**6)).tolist()

spark_rfft_bins = F.udf(_fft_bins, T.ArrayType(T.DoubleType(), False))

def _abs_complex(complex_tuple_list):
    return list([abs(complex(real, imag)) for real, imag in complex_tuple_list])

spark_abs_complex = F.udf(_abs_complex, T.ArrayType(T.DoubleType()))

# df incoming from builder

fftDf = df.withColumn('fft', spark_rfft(col('data'))) \
    .withColumn('fftFreq', spark_rfft_bins('dataDim', 'samplePeriod')) \
    .withColumn('fftAbs', spark_abs_complex('fft'))

avgDf = fftDf.select(F.avg('fftAbs'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```py
def _index_avg(twoDL):
    return np.mean(twoDL, axis=0).tolist()

spark_index_avg = F.udf(_index_avg, T.ArrayType(T.DoubleType(), False))
avgDf = df.agg(spark_index_avg(F.collect_list('fftAbs')))
```

I'm sure someone will come along with a better answer, but this seems to work for now.

EDIT: Yeah this didn't work for larger sets of data

Answer (score 1):

What about to use `posexplode`?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[[0, 1, 2]],[[2, 3, 12]],[[1, 8, 4]]]).toDF('array')

df.select(f.posexplode('array')) \
  .groupBy('pos') \
  .agg(f.avg('col').alias('avg')) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+---+---+
|pos|avg|
+---+---+
|1  |4.0|
|2  |6.0|
|0  |1.0|
+---+---+
```

If you have another field, you can use the `Window` but there can be a performance issue.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['a', [0, 1, 2]],['b', [2, 3, 12]],['b', [1, 8, 4]]], ['col1', 'array'])

w = Window.partitionBy(f.lit(1))

df.withColumn('avg', f.array(*[f.avg(f.col('array')[i]).over(w) for i in range(0, 3)])) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+----+----------+---------------+
|col1|array     |avg            |
+----+----------+---------------+
|a   |[0, 1, 2] |[1.0, 4.0, 6.0]|
|b   |[2, 3, 12]|[1.0, 4.0, 6.0]|
|b   |[1, 8, 4] |[1.0, 4.0, 6.0]|
+----+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: That is actually a really good idea! But how would you handle it if the df also had some other fields? (that I need to group against)